# Creating a Google Apps Script to change other Apps Script Files

Tags: google-apps-script

I have quite a few spreadsheets that are exactly the same - one for each user, so that each user doesn't see another's information.  Each spreadsheet has it's own script file (runOnEdit), once again they are all identical.  Each of these spreadsheets/script files (runOnEdit) interacts via API with the server - much like React-Node does.

Periodically there are changes that need to be made to each of the many spreadsheets' script (runOnEdit) files.  Since they are all the same, it is pretty much a copy, paste, & save of the new code over top of the old code in each of the existing spreadsheet's script file (runOnEdit).

I know I've seen that you can write a script that will loop through all of the spreadsheets, replacing the existing code in the existing script file(s) for each, but I can't find it through searching the web now.

Thank you!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest

Comment: Thank you, @Cooper!  I think that is what I needed.  I've seen this before, but couldn't find my way back to it.  Within that, this is what I need to use: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent.

Comment: A link to it is on the header for google apps script documentation

Comment: Hi @Cooper ! Could you please formalise the reference in your comment into an answer so that other users having trouble finding this can easily see the right answer? Many thanks ! :D